# XJR 1300 2001. Revving high after fixing a throttle stick problem

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

Rode today after 3 years . New filter and plugs. Reconnected throttle cable after it stuck. But it's still revving really high. Any clues folks ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm assuming you properly resolved the original issue with the throttle cable and reconnected it properly but you may want to double check all that anyway.  What about any air or vacuum lines or any electrical connectors that you moved or had to disconnect?  Have then been properly reconnected?